# UINavigationController pushing UITabBarController only displays one tab

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application that has a `UITabBarController` created in IB.  That tbc loads 3 views which work fine up to now.

I decided to INSERT a `UINavController` as the starting VC and have a `UITableViewController` display 4 menu items in cells. Each of the 4 items will in essence load the `UITabBarController` put pass in a different xml file to process in order to display data in those 3 tabs.

I essentially did this at the end of the `applicationDidFinishLoading`:

```
MainMenu *rootViewController = [[MainMenu alloc] init];
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

I then created the MainMenu as the `rootViewController` subclassing `UITableViewController` and added a hardcoded array for now which displays the 4 items I want.  I had the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` run this code:

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
[tabBarController release];
```

It turns out that when I run it, the navcontroller pushes the tab controller but only the first tab shows up.  Here is a pic.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should never push a `UITabBarController` from a `UINavigationController`. Apple clearly says this:

*An app that uses a tab bar controller can also use navigation controllers in one or more tabs. When combining these two types of view controller in the same user interface, **the tab bar controller always** acts as the wrapper for the navigation controllers.`*

That essentially means tab bar should be the parent of all other view controllers that get called. Not the other way round. You should probably change the way you present your app.

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html).

Comment: Check Apple New App, they seem to push UITabBarController into a UINavigationController

Comment: would you be able to update the link? apparently it is no longer valid.